# The greatest prime factor of $6n+1$

Tags: number-theory

Let $p(n)$ be the greatest prime factor of $n$. Denote $a_1(n)=p(6n+1),a_{k+1}(n)=p(6a_k(n)+1)).$

Is it true that for $\forall n\in \mathbb N,$ $\exists c,t \in \mathbb N^{+}:k>c\implies a_{k+t}(n)=a_k(n)?$

In other words, $a_k(n)$ will not $\to \infty$ when $k\to \infty.$

I have checked for $n<10^6,$ and $t$ always $<100$.

Comment: I don't think it helps, but unless $6n+1$ is prime or $5*$prime, then $p(6n+1)<n$ as soon as $n>7$.